# ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I wrote this code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import numpy as np
import cv2, base64

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
PADDING = '{'

pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

secret = "youwanttoknowmysecretdontyouhaha"
cipher = AES.new(secret)

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a = 0

while True:
    a = a + 1

    check, frame = video.read()

    encrypted = EncodeAES(cipher, str(frame))

    img = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted)

    cv2.imshow("Capturing", np.ndarray(img))
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

But it doesnt work like it supposed to.

I want it to play my live camera, but it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tester.py", line 28, in
>   
>       cv2.imshow("Capturing", np.ndarray(img)) ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32

I really would like to know what Im doing wrong and dont give me only the solution but explain to please, im still learning

**EDIT**

I use python 2.7

**EDIT**

The following code works, but I use it in a program where the host sends the encrypted to an other computer. In this case you cant use `frame.dtype`.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import numpy as np
import cv2, base64

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
PADDING = '{'

pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

secret = "youwanttoknowmysecretdontyouhaha"
cipher = AES.new(secret)

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a = 0

while True:
    a = a + 1

    check, frame = video.read()

    encrypted = EncodeAES(cipher, frame.tobytes())

    decrypted = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted)

    img = np.frombuffer(decrypted, dtype=frame.dtype).reshape(frame.shape)

    cv2.imshow("Capturing", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

video.release()
```

However I can send frame.dtype to the other computer.

When I send the the encrypted form of `frame.dtype` and `frame_shape` to the computer and decrypt it and use it there, I get the following error

```
img = np.frombuffer(decod_ed, dtype=img_dtype).reshape(img_shape)
TypeError: data type "ûÿùùÖÿùÖÿùÖÿÖÖÿÖÖÿÜÜÖøøÜ£ÜÖ£ÜÖÜÜÖÜÜÖÿÜÜÿÜÜÿÜøÖø£øøøøøøØ£ÿØ£ÿØ£ÿƒ×ÜØ×Ü×ƒøØƒÖøØùØØùØØùƒ£ÿ×øùƒ£ÿƒ£ÿƒøÜƒøÜíØ£íØ£íØ£ó×Øó×Øó×Øóƒøóƒøúá£óƒøáƒøáƒø×ƒø×ƒø£ƒø£ƒø£ƒø£ƒøƒ×ÜáƒøúíøúíøÑáøÑáøñ×øÑƒ£ñØ×Ñ×ƒñáƒñáƒóíØíá£áó£ƒíø×áÜ×áÜøƒÖ£áÜ£ƒø£ƒøƒØ£ƒØ£á×Øá×ØØØ£ØØ£××Øƒƒ×ƒƒ×××Ø×ƒø×ƒø£ƒø£ƒø£×Ø£×Ø£×Ø£×ØØá£Øá£ØíøØíøáó£áó£×ó£ØíøÜƒøù£ÿôÜÿôÜÿÿÜÜÿÜÜøøøØØØíƒ×óáƒíƒ×íƒ×óáƒóáƒñúƒñúƒªÑíñúƒñúƒñúƒúó×úó×úó×úó×óó£óó£úñøúñøúúØññ×óñ×óñ×óúƒóúƒóóíóóíóúƒñÑíóªááñ××ñ××ñ××úƒáÑí×ºá×ºá£ñƒ£ñƒáúƒáúƒññúóóíúíáúíáííáññúññúññúñÑíñÑíóúƒñÑíñÑíñÑíóÑíóÑíóúƒóúƒñÑíñÑíñÑíóúƒáúƒóÑíóÑíáúƒƒó×áúƒóÑíóÑíóÑíáúƒáúƒƒó×ƒó××íØØíøØíøØóÖØóÖØíø£áÜááÜƒƒÖíƒÖƒØùØ×òƒáùØáùÜØöÜØöÜØöÖ×òÿØöù£ôù£ôûÜöûÜööÜööÜöÆøöÆøööÜööÜöûÜööÿÆûùôûùôÿûòûöôÆöôöûòöûòöûòöûòÆöôÉòæÉòæÉûÉÉûÉÅòÅÅòÅæòÅÉöÄÉöÄÉöÄÉöÄÅôìÉÆîÅæïææïÉÉèÉÅåÉÅåîÅåèìäçîâåïéêîüêîüçï~çï~àïÇàïÇë|å|" not understood
```

Comment: most probably the shape of the image is something like (480, 640, 3) and the shape of the decrypted image is (921600)... you need to reshape the array to the correct shape

Comment: Don't use `ndarray`. Use `np.array(img)`,  The first argument for `ndarray` is the shape, which can't longer than 32 elements.  Review the docs in cases like this.

Comment: @hpaulj if I replace `np.ndarray(img)` with `np.array(img)` I get this error: `TypeError: mat data type = 18 is not supported`

Comment: OK, `img is a special kind of object, buffer or bytestring, that requires a kind of decoding that `np.array` can't handle.  In any case it certainly doesn't qualify as the `shape` parameter for `ndarray`.

Comment: If it's on the other computer, there's the code duplicated as well. But that's not important. Anyway the *dtype* and shape need to be serialized/deserialized as well. For them yu can simply use str.

Comment: @CristiFati I still dont know how to do it. I've ben strugling getting the string back to tuples. Again Im just a beginner, could you edit your awnser?

Comment: Already did, (after posting the comment).

Comment: @CristiFati I get the following error: `img = np.frombuffer(decrypted_data, dtype=np.dtype(meta[0])).reshape(meta[1])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 768 into shape (480,640,3)`

Comment: Then probably you messed up the buffer again, bringing you back to square 1.

Comment: @CristiFati When I just use the scipt you gave me, it works, but when I send the encrypted data with the module socket to an other computer it gives me this error: `img = np.frombuffer(decrypted_data, dtype=np.dtype(meta[0])).reshape(meta[1])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 768 into shape (480,640,3)`

Comment: It's exactly what I said. You are messing the buffer. There is some extra code that does that. I suppose that not everything you send over the network arrives at the destination (or at least you don't read it). But anyway that's a totally different question which has nothing to do with the current one.

Comment: @CristiFati, is it ok if I edit this quistion? I cant ask any new quistions

Comment: Feel free to edit it, but as far as I'm concerned this question has already transformed into an endless stream of questions , which are moving far away from the original one. What do you mean by "*cant ask any new quistions*"?

Comment: @CristiFati, When I press Ask Quistion it says: You have reached your question limit
It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!

Comment: At the beginning I thought it's because you don't have answered questions, but there are users with way more unanswered questions than you. Apparently there are some limits: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide. So I suggest to try posting other questions, and if the error keeps popping up, save the questions in files, and paste them again (1, 2 days) later, to avoid duplicating the annoying process of editing and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that *frame* is a [[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). There are 2 problems. Below is an example:

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import numpy as np
import cv2
import base64


BLOCK_SIZE = 16
PADDING = b"{"

pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

CIPHER_MODE = AES.MODE_CBC
SECRET = b"youwanttoknowmysecretdontyouhaha"


def main():

    img0 = cv2.imread("c:/valmand.png")
    encrypt_cipher = AES.new(SECRET, CIPHER_MODE)  # Python 2: AES.new(SECRET)
    print("Original image data - Type: {:}, Size: {:d}, Attrs: {:}".format(type(img0), img0.size, img0.shape))
    img_stream_wrong = str(img0).encode()
    print("\nWrong img0 stream length: {:}".format(len(img_stream_wrong)))
    print("\nWrong img0 stream: {:}".format(img_stream_wrong))
    img_stream = img0.tobytes()
    print("\nCorrect img0 stream length: {:}".format(len(img_stream)))
    encrypted = EncodeAES(encrypt_cipher, img_stream)
    print("\nEncrypted length: {:d}".format(len(encrypted)))
    decrypt_cipher = AES.new(SECRET, CIPHER_MODE)  # Python 2: AES.new(SECRET)
    decrypted = DecodeAES(decrypt_cipher, encrypted)
    print("\nDecrypted length: {:d}".format(len(decrypted)))
    img1 = np.frombuffer(decrypted, dtype=img0.dtype).reshape(img0.shape)
    print("\nFinal image data - Type: {:}, Size: {:d}, Attrs: {:}".format(type(img1), img1.size, img1.shape))
    #cv2.imshow("Capturing", img1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I simplified the example to only load an image
- Since I don't have all the required packages installed on *Python 2*, I used *Python 3*. That's why some changes unrelated to the question were required:

  - Switch from *string* to *bytes*
  - *AES* changes:

    - `AES.new` signature changed ([[ReadTheDocs.PyCryptodome]: AES](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html))
    - Same cipher can't be used for decryption after it was used for encryption, so create another with the same properties (maybe there's some cleaner way of doing this, but I didn't spend too much time on it)
- **The errors**:

  - As seen, applying *str* on an *ndarray*, gives a user friendly representation of that *ndarray*, rather than its contents, so it will be ***syntactically* correct, but *semantically* wrong**

    - To fix that, the array should be properly serialized using its ***tobytes*** method
  - Conversely, when deserialization is attempted, **the *ndarray* constructor is invoked** on the byte stream, (which is silently converted to a *tuple* of *int*s - that the constructor expects - having the same length as the stream)

    - The problem here is that the **constructor doesn't accept sequences larger than *32***:

      > ```py
      > >>> np.ndarray([0] * 32)
      > array([], shape=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      >       dtype=float64)
      > >>> np.ndarray([0] * 33)
      > Traceback (most recent call last):
      >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      > ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
      > ```
    - To fix it, [[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.frombuffer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) should be used. For the new *ndarray* to be equal to the original one, 2 more things are required (data needed from the original):

      - Its *dtype* should be specified (default is *float* and we need *uint8*)
      - Needs to be reshaped

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054326620>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Original image data - Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, Size: 1493331, Attrs: (799, 623, 3)
>
> Wrong img0 stream length: 629
>
> Wrong img0 stream: b'[[[255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  ...\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]]\n\n [[255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  ...\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]]\n\n [[255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  ...\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]]\n\n ...\n\n [[255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  ...\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]]\n\n [[255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  ...\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]]\n\n [[255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  ...\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]\n  [255 255 255]]]'
>
> Correct img0 stream length: 1493331
>
> Encrypted length: 1991128
>
> Decrypted length: 1493331
>
> Final image data - Type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, Size: 1493331, Attrs: (799, 623, 3)
> ```

***@EDIT0***:

Apparently, there are some compatibility problems. I developed the answer using *Python 3* and *pycrpytodome* ***3.7.2***. I upgraded to latest (*3.7.3*), I've also installed it on *Python 2*, and the code above works. Here's what I get in the console:

> ```py
> >>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
> >>> AES
> <module 'Crypto.Cipher.AES' from 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_02.07.15_test0\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.pyc'>
> >>> AES.new("")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: new() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
> >>> import Crypto
> >>> Crypto.__version__
> '3.7.3'
> ```

So, you probably have a terribly old *pycryptodome* version. Anyway, I'm **blindly** posting the changes required by your code, to incorporate the fixes (the *while* loop **only**):

```py
# The rest of your code (exactly as in the question)

while True:
    a = a + 1

    check, frame = video.read()

    original_meta = frame.dtype.name, frame.shape

    encrypted_meta = EncodeAES(cipher, bytes(original_meta))
    encrypted_data = EncodeAES(cipher, frame.tobytes())

    # Here is the separation

    decrypted_meta = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted_meta)
    decrypted_data = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted_data)

    meta = ast.literal_eval(decrypted_meta)

    img = np.frombuffer(decrypted_data, dtype=np.dtype(meta[0])).reshape(meta[1])

    cv2.imshow("Capturing", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: Why the b before the variables?

Comment: And sorry for not not telling you, but I use python 2, so the `print("")` should be `print ""`, any thing else I need to change besides the usr/bin thing?

Comment: One last thing. If I use your code I get this error: `encrypt_cipher = AES.new(SECRET, CIPHER_MODE)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 95, in new
    return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 59, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long`

Comment: As I explained, many changes are related to *Python 3* (I realize that you're using 2, hence the first part of the notes). The *b* is for *bytes*. `print("")` works in *Python 2* as well. For *AES* you need to remove the 2nd argument (like in your original code). I'll add some comments in the code.

Comment: So as a conclusion, change the 1st line to `#!/usr/bin/env python`, then the 2 *AES* initializations (where I put the comments), the prints can remain as they are (or you can remove them altogether), and in *Python2* the ***b*** in front of strings has no effect.

Comment: For `ndarray`, the first (and only) positional argument is the `shape`.  The data is provided in a separate `buffer` parameter.  `ndarray` is a low level constructor that should not be used by novices (or most anyone else).

Comment: @CristiFati I have both python 2 and 3 installed on my system. They both gave the same error I gave you. And I know I can use print("") in python 2, but it isnt really meant to be used like that

Comment: I know that *print* will output a tuple, but that's not the point, *print*s are in my code for clarity only. You didn't have any in yours. So if you remove  *CIPHER\_MODE* argument, doesn't it work? Your error is strange. I have `pycryptodome==3.7.2` (just upgraded to latest (3.7.3)) and without the 2nd arg, it triggers error. I will update the answer, and I'll post blindly the changes you need in your code, and also some details about my environment. Maybe we are talking about different `Crypto.Cipher.AES`

Comment: @hpaulj: you're the expert! Anyway, just out of curiosity, I've tested `np.ndarray(img0.shape, buffer=decrypted, dtype=img0.dtype)`, and apparently the arrays seem to have the same properties (of cours, I have no idea what happens under the hood).

Comment: @CristiFati I used the `AES.new(SECRET)` On the places where you put them and I forgot to create a picture called valmand.png on the c drive. I did both and now it works. but 1 last problem if I add `cv2.imshow("Capturing", img1)` to the script and then `time.sleep(2)`, because other wise it will only show the picture for 100th of a second. But when I see the picture its all gray. not the picture in gray filter, the photo is just a gray canvas.

Comment: And I dont use pycryptodome. I had some errors so I just use crypto, not pycryptodome. here are some pip freeze outputs of mine about crypto `cryptography==2.2.2` and `pycrypto==2.6.1` and `pycryptodomex==3.6.3`

Comment: @CristiFati, Hi I the updated version of my code worked, but it doesnt in the way I want. I'm going to update my quistion