# Numpy np.fromstring() not working as hoped

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I have saved an array in a text file as a string hoping I would be able to convert it back into an array when read from file:

```
str_arr = "[0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01]"
num_arr = np.fromstring(str_arr,dtype = np.float64 ,count = 6,sep = ' ')
```

the result of whic is `num_array`:

```
array([-1.00000000e+000,  6.94819184e-310,  6.94819184e-310,
        6.94818751e-310,  6.94818751e-310,  6.94818751e-310])
```

I was expecting an array of `0.01`s

Comment: `arr.tolist()` can be saved as JSON, preserving the nesting of brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you saved your array in the file using *str*. That's wrong. 
Although in this case, the error is not visible, for larger arrays, it will become clear that the value saved this way will yield an incorrect buffer. Check [[SO]: ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326620/valueerror-sequence-too-large-cannot-be-greater-than-32/54328023#54328023) for more details.

Although there are trivial ways to get past the current situation (extra processing on the existing string), they would only be workarounds (*gainarii*), while the proper way (or, at least one of them) to solve would be to **correctly serialize the array**  (using [[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.ndarray.tostring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html)) when saving it to file.

> ```py
> >>> arr = np.array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])
> >>> arr
> array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])
> >>>
> >>> str_arr0 = str(arr)
> >>> str_arr0
> '[0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01]'
> >>> str_arr1 = arr.tostring()
> >>> str_arr1
> b'{\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x84?{\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x84?{\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x84?{\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x84?{\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x84?{\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x84?'
> >>>
> >>> arr_final = np.fromstring(str_arr1, dtype=np.float64)
> >>> arr_final
> array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])
> >>>
> >>> arr_final_wrong = np.fromstring(str_arr0[1:-1], dtype=np.float64, count=6, sep= " ")
> >>> arr_final_wrong
> array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])
> >>>
> >>> arr = np.array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01] * 10)
> >>> # This time, str(arr) will produce an invalid result
> ...
> >>> str(arr)
> '[0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01\n 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01\n 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01\n 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01\n 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01]'
> ```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that [`np.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) does not know how to interpret the brackets. You could solve that by stripping them before calling the function:

```
a = "[0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01]"
num_arr = np.fromstring(a.strip('[]'), count = 6, sep = ' ')

array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])
```

Also note that, `dtype` defaults to `float`, so there's no need to specify it in this case.

Comment: quick and correct @yatu thanks. Is it correct etiquette to accept an answer so quickly or should I let it simmer for a while? incidentally I am also in Barca...

Comment: Well @seanysull that depends on the kind of answer you're expecting, but IMO this is the simplest solution for this specific problem. Good to know! ( Barcelona though, here we only call Barça the football team, not the city :-)

Comment: Both answers are really correct.  This one answers, but my input is in this format I cannot turn back the clock.  The other one is how things should be done in the future.  I do find it odd though that fromstring does not handle brackets.  What use case were they considering?

Comment: No idea, presumably the array was not correctly serialized as Cristi points out @demongolem